update dictionaries in the list comprehension
There is a dictionary:
d = [{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]

I'd like to update values of keys b.
d = [{**m}.update({"b":5}) for m in d]

but I don't understand why this gives
d = [None, None, None]
I'd expect
d = [{"a":1, "b":5},{"a":3, "b":5},{"a":5, "b":5}]

dict.update does not return anything. Do not do list comprehension for side-effects.

There's no reason to use a list comprehension here. You want to update, in-place, the elements of an existing list, not create a new list. Use a regular for loop.

Is this answer your question?

dict.update returns None and updates the dict in-place. You can try using the | operator which returns a new dict:
d = [m | {"b":5} for m in d]


cool, I didn't know this dictionary merge operator!

Yeah it's really helpful! Please consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem!

You should use a regular for loop to apply update to each existing dict, not create a new list of new dicts.
list_of_d = [{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]

for d in list_of_d:
    d.update(b=5)

List comprehensions are not just "one-line for loops".

Because update modifies an object in place, you could use a list comprehension and ignore the resulting list, but I don't recommend this. You don't want a list of None values, and you shouldn't create it just for the side effect of d.update.
>>> list_of_d = [{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]
>>> [d.update(b=5) for d in list_of_d]
[None, None, None]
>>> list_of_d
[{'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 5}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]


I'd say d["b"] = 5 is way more usual (and likely faster), I didn't even know d.update(b=5).

Yeah, I just stuck with d.update to emphasize the side effect. In addition to a mapping, update can take an iterable of key/value pairs or arbitrary keyword arguments. Useful if you need to update multiple keys at once, but unnecessary overhead for a single key update.

The reason why you are getting d = [None, None, None] is because dict.update does not return any value. Generally it is recommended to avoid using list comprehensions to have side effects on the elements because readers may stumble trying to understand the intent. This could be a use case for the built in map function.
d = [{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]

list(map(lambda x: x.update({"b":5}), d))

# Elements of d are now updated


But I think generally when processing iterables where the function you're calling has desirable side effects on the elements it is cleanest to use a for loop.
d = [{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]

for x in d:
    x.update({"b":5},d)

